# Hide product in catalog page

Tags: magento2, css

how i can hide products from catalog listing only but keep showing them in search result page using css like `display: none;`, is there a way to create a customer ID for the specific products that i want to hide and control the visibility via css?

Comment: Use visibility In admin magento

Answer (score 1):

There is a default setting in Magento where you can define **visibility** of your products.

If you set this option for **"Search"** - Products will be visible on Search Result Page

If you set this option for **"Catalog"** - Products will be visible on Catalog Listing Page

If you set this option for **"Catalog, Search"** - Products will be visible on both Catalog Listing Page and Search Result Page

[image]

**Solution 2:** I **will not** recommend (the way you want)

- Create Boolean Attribute at product level (Yes/No)
- call that attribute in your tag `<li>` tag

`<li class="item product product-item <?php if($_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code')){ echo 'hide'; } ?>">`

In **CSS** `hide { display: none; }`

By this way you can hide any product you want. Again I will **NOT RECOMMEND** this way.

Comment: thank you for the fast reply, but i want to have some specific product to hide in catalog and show in search

Comment: So you can change this setting for specific products only. Then Re-index and are good to go :)

Comment: Use default Magento rather then using CSS or some customization

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek it didn't work, my best chance is to use a css class

```
 `<li class="item product product-item hide">      `
```

and i will use `hide { display: none; }`

how i can add css class to a specific product?

Comment: What do you mean by it didnt work?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: thank you again :) one last question what file i need to edit to add
<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code')){ echo 'hide'; } ?>

to

<li class="item product product-item">

Comment: I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'attribute_code' (T_STRING)

Comment: Can you please tell me your `attribute_code` which you created in Admin?

Comment: attribute code is hide

Comment: `$_product->getData('hide');` use this code to get 1 or 0..

Comment: this is my line

<li class="item product product-item <?php if($_ pooduct->getData('hide'); } ?>">


and this is the error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'hide' (T_STRING) in /home/monarchwebdev/public_html/app/design/frontend/Ortho/_honourFurniture/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml on line 115

Comment: Its `$_product` . use your product object

Comment: i changed my line to 

<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item <?php if($_ product->getData('hide'); } ?>">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>

still  

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'hide' (T_STRING) in /home/monarchwebdev/public_html/app/design/frontend/Ortho/_honourFurniture/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml on line 115

Comment: `<li class="item product product-item <?php if($_product->getData('hide') == 1) { echo 'hide'; } ?>">`

Comment: still
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'hide' (T_STRING) in /home/monarchwebdev/public_html/app/design/frontend/Ortho/_honourFurniture/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml on line 115

Comment: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item <?php if($_product->getData('hide') == 1) { echo 'hide'; } ?>">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>

Comment: those are my setting in admin ( print screen )

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/894ac7e79935641a25b6e20d24e1019b20171215160141/cf4556f50143b724d0c5988c4a420f2320171215160141/27a446

Comment: Abhishek  any help please

Answer (score 0):

how i can add this line

```
    `<?php if($_product->getData('hide') == 1) { echo 'hide'; } ?>`
```

to

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item ***HERE***">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
```